# how to get week +4 in this day with carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a problem here I want to get the +4 week date from the current date using carbon, the +4 week plan will be dynamic depending on the input entered by the user, how do I make it, I've tried using this code but it's time to step back

```
 $dt = Carbon::now();
        dd($dt->week(4)->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: this code doesn't work?..

Comment: this doesn't work, my expect is 2020-03-24 (+4 week) , but the output is 2020-01-21

Comment: and if you dump the Carbon::now() what does it print?

Comment: it should be         `dd($dt->addWeeks(4)->format('Y-m-d'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Carbon docs, you may use [`addWeeks()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub):

```php
$dt = Carbon::now();
dd($dt->addWeeks(4)->format('Y-m-d'));
```

The [`week()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/reference/#doc-method-Carbon-week) method you've used, sets the week number using given first day of week and first day of year included in the first week.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question, but I guess you just have to use :

```
$dt = Carbon::now();
$dt->addWeeks(4);

dd($dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need carbon for such simple tasks.
With DateTime

```
echo date_create('+4 weeks')->format("Y-m-d");
```

or with date and strtotime

```
echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+4 weeks'));
```